# SQL Server T-SQL: Get a records set based on a priority value, startdate and enddate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on an time attendance system. I have to following tables:

- `Schedule`: Contains a Name `nvarchar` field and a Start and End `DateTime` fields.
- `Policy`: Contains Start and End `DateTime` fields too.
- `PolicySchedule` (Cross Table): Contains a Priority `int` field beside the foreign keys.

End datetime fields are nullable which indicates open periods.

The schedule of the greatest priority will be applied and activated within its time and the policy time.

I need to get a list of the applied schedules within each policy and their activation periods start and end time knowing that shedules may be intersected. Policies are not related here ..

**Example:**

```
Schedule_____________Start_________________________End

Schedule1____________01/01/2011 00:00______________04/01/2011 00:00
Schedule2____________04/01/2011 00:00______________11/01/2011 14:00
Schedule3____________11/01/2011 14:00______________02/15/2012 00:00
Schedule2____________02/15/2012 00:00______________01/01/2013 00:00
```

What is the most efficient way to get the requested result ?

Comment: Can the start and end times intersect on policies as well?

Comment: @Quassnoi: No, policies are independent. I need the result set for each policy seperately ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use an `outer apply` to look up the policy with the highest priority:

```
select  *
from    Schedule s
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    PolicySchedule ps
        join    Policy p
        on      p.id = ps.policyid
        where   s.StartTime <= p.EndTime
                and p.StartTime <= s.EndTime
        order by
                ps.priority desc
        ) pol
```

If there are time periods that have to overlap, you can add a `where` clause in the outer apply.

Comment: This does not take into account the effective dates for the policies.

Comment: If I got it right, this returns the highest priority policy for each schedule. What I actualy want is the applied/active schedule portion for each policy ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of policies and schedules (separately) but few schedules per policy, the most straightforward way would be quite efficient:

```
WITH    dates (policyId, changeDate) AS
        (
        SELECT  policyId, changeDate,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY policyId ORDER BY changeDate) AS rn
        FROM    (
                SELECT  policyId, startDate AS changeDate
                FROM    policySchedule ps
                JOIN    schedule s
                ON      s.id = ps.scheduleId
                UNION
                SELECT  policyId, endDate AS changeDate
                FROM    policySchedule ps
                JOIN    schedule s
                ON      s.id = ps.scheduleId
                ) q
        ),
        ranges (startDate, endDate)AS
        (
        SELECT  d1.policyId,
                d1.changeDate,
                d2.changeDate
        FROM    dates d1
        JOIN    dates d2
        ON      d2.policyId = d1.policyId
                AND d2.rn = d1.rn + 1
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    policy p
JOIN    ranges r
ON      r.policyId = p.id
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 s.*
        FROM    policySchedules ps
        JOIN    schedule s
        ON      ps.policyId = p.id
                AND s.id = ps.scheduleId
        WHERE   ps.startDate BETWEEN r.startDate AND r.endDate
                AND ps.endDate BETWEEN r.startDate AND r.endDate
        ORDER BY
                ps.Priority DESC
        )
```